# Using Fetch in react, need username password to access database

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, fetch

I have done hours of research on this and just can't find the answer I need. Sorry if this has been asked and I have been bad in my research, if so just link the helpful stack overflow page and I'll be on my merry way. Here is the summary of my problem.

I am in a CS4 class and we are designing our own webpage and must use our school's server for database storage. We learned php and how to use mySQL and our POST and GET requests for the server would look like this (written in PHP):

```
require("config.php");

$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . $GLOBALS["database"] . ";host=" . $GLOBALS["hostname"] . ";port=" . $GLOBALS["port"], 
$GLOBALS["username"], $GLOBALS["password"]);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Karrsen_ajaxtest"; 
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    print(strip_tags($row['name']) . "<br/>");
}
```

Where the config was set correctly.

Now I am doing my final project it React.js and have to request from the same server. I want to use the built in Fetch system but it throws CORS errors and I also don't know how to add the aforementioned username, password, database, and hostname. I have looked through the MDN webdocs thoroughly (thought it might be request Header, Credentials, Mode, or Integrity?) but didn't find much besides it saying if have to add myself to Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the server (but I cannot edit the settings of my school server.)

How do I add these credentials? Will I continue to get a CORS error. Sorry if this is a waste of your time, don't know too much about stack overflow

*EDIT
I have my react app in which my only component right now will be some login stuff. It is called Login.JS. Right now all I want it to do is get the data from the database on submit of the form. Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';

class Login extends React.Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        userName: "",
        password: "",
        hits: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    this.updateFromDB();
  }

  formValidation() {
    return this.state.password.length > 0 && this.state.userName.length > 0;
  }

  updateFromDB(){
    let API = "THE_URL_FOR_MY_DATABASE";
    let query = "SELECT * FROM karrsen_test";
    fetch(API + query, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits }));
  }

  render (){
    return(
        <div className= "Login-form">
            <form onSubmit = {(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                <label>
                    Username:
                    <input 
                    type = "text" 
                    value = {this.state.userName} 
                    onChange = {this.handleChange} 
                    name = "userName"/>
                </label>
                <label> 
                    Password:
                    <input
                    type = "text"
                    value = {this.state.password}
                    onChange = {this.handleChange}
                    name = "password" />
                </label>
                <input 
                    disabled = {!this.formValidation()}
                    type = "submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )

  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Hi Karrsen, welcome to SO! Do you mind editing your question to include the specific error you are getting? Also, do you mind showing the part of your code where you use `fetch`? Thanks!

Comment: Of course! One minute. Should have done that to begin with! My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CORS is enabled by [default](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api#cross-origin_requests) with `fetch`, but your server will need to be configured to handle cross origin requests.

Assuming your school's server is running Apache, you should be able to do that by adding an .htaccess file to your PHP directory. Simply name the file `.htaccess` and add the following line.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This requires the Apache server to be configured to allow overrides in the `DocumentRoot`. The `DocumentRoot` is the root directory that Apache is hosting. For example, say you're hosting example.com from the `/var/www/example` directory. `/var/www/example` is the DocumentRoot.

In the Apache configuration for example.com, the `AllowOverride` directive must be set to allow the `.htaccess` file to override the base configuration - otherwise the `.htaccess` file is ignored.

To enable Apache to control and modify HTTP request and response headers, the `mod_headers` module must be enabled. From a terminal, enter the following command.

```
a2enmod headers
```

If all else fails, you can try editing the response (from the server) HTTP header with PHP, by adding the following line to your PHP script - probably at the top before anything else.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
```

Comment: I was going to write the same answer. CORS should be enabled in the server to allow fetching from a different domain.

Comment: Sure seems like that's the issue @DineshPandiyan, but I'm making the assumption the school is using a LAMP server - odds are. But the same concept would apply to any Web server that I'm aware of.

Comment: Cors is not _always_ the default (it's never the default in Chrome for example), and you should always make sure to set `mode: 'cors'` when using fetch if that is what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request

Comment: @MatthewHerbst in the link to the Google developer documentation on fetch in my post, it says "The CORS mechanism lets you specify in a request that you want to retrieve a cross-origin resource (in fetch this is enabled by default)." In their example it says `mode: 'cors'` is the default. Maybe I'm misreading something?

Comment: @Jason Microsoft and MDN are disagreeing. I tend to trust MDN. Of course, only one of the two can be correct. The [official spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) (we all know browsers are 100% spec-compliant, right!? :D) says: "A request has an associated mode, which is "same-origin", "cors", "no-cors", "navigate", or "websocket". Unless stated otherwise, it is "no-cors".

Comment: @MatthewHerbst given the conflict, and cross-browser issues, I'd say it couldn't hurt - and may help - to set the `fetch` to explicitly use CORS. Thanks!

Comment: Hey all! Thanks for the info, but I don't believe I am allowed to edit the server settings for my class (since it belongs to the school and not me.) With the PHP example we could POST and GET just fine, no access was denied because I had the password and all. Is there no way using JS to implement something like that? If I'm being dumb just tell me.

Comment: @KarrsenB JavaScript, in this case, is running on the browser side. The CORS issue is most likely on the server side. The `.htaccess` provides a way for non-server-admins to override the server configuration. Hosting providers often enable it - as your school quite possibly has. If that doesn't work, you can try adding the header line at the bottom of my post to your PHP script. FYI, if you're having issues with AJAX, it's a good idea to post the request sent and response received.